# Indexing all items excluding an index from the back

Tags: python, numpy

I want to slice a numpy array such that an index, -7 for example, is excluded. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a double slicing?

```
a = np.arange(10)*10
#                    -7
# array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])

idx = -7
np.r_[a[:idx], a[idx+1:]]
```

Output:

```
array([ 0, 10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
```